# Как вернуть значение из класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Суть проблемы:*

Допустим есть класс **Ball** и если он создается без атрибута **name**, то нужно вернуть из метода **ball_type** значение **"regular"**, а если есть любое другое значение, то вывести нужно **"super"**.

*Мой код:*

```
class Ball (object):
    name = ""

    def ball_type (self):
    
        if self.name == "":
            return regular

        else:
            return super


print (Ball ().ball_type, "regular")
print (Ball ("super").ball_type, "super")
```

*Вывод с консоли:*

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

надо добавить метод `__init__` который принимает не обязательный параметр `name`.Но в этом случае вам надо вызвать `ball_type`

```
class Ball (object):
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
        self.name = name
        
    def ball_type (self):
        if self.name == "":
            return "regular"
        else:
            return "super"


print (Ball().ball_type(), "regular")
print (Ball("super").ball_type(), "super")
```

либо создавать `ball_type` в `__init__`. В этом случае вызывать не надо

```
class Ball (object):
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
        self.name = name
        self.ball_type = "super" if name else "regular"

print (Ball().ball_type, "regular")
print (Ball("super").ball_type, "super")
```

Comment: А можно про первый случай поподробнее, почему компилятор вот в таком виде интерпретирует строку ?                                                                                                                                                             
 ||| <bound method Ball.ball_type of <__main__.Ball object at 0x0000020213A81BE0>> regular |||

Comment: потому что `ball_type` это функция и её нужно вызвать т.е. добавить круглые скобки `ball_type()`